# Regular expression pattern /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[^w{3}]/ not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the http:// or https:// without 'www' with 'www'. I am using this below pattern,

```
/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[^w{3}]/
```

but not working. 
Here is the text where I am searching

> the url is http://google.com http://www.google.com https://google.com
>   https://google.com

https://regex101.com/r/JhMN6t/1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everyone posts part of their answer and then fill in the explanation.... the dark side of SO.

Comment: @Mark What exactly you did mean  ?

Answer (score 2):

`[^w{3}]` matches a single character that is not `w` or `{` or `3` or `}`.

You want to use a negative look-ahead assertion instead:

```
/https?:\/\/(?!www)/

// or maybe even
/https?:\/\/(?!www\.)/
```

`(?!www)` means "not followed by *www*".

Answer (score 1):

you can use this regex: `(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(?!www)`

`(?!` is a negative lookahead, it ensures it doesn't follow with what's specified inside, without consuming the characters

https://regex101.com/r/6TEv2r/1

Answer (score 1):

You are using a negated character class `[^w{3}]` which does not match one of `w`, `{`, `}` or `3`.

You could use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert what is on the right is not www. and replace with the first capturing group followed by www and a dot.

Note that the alternation can be shortened to `https?` making the s optional using a questionmark.

Match

```
const regex = /(https?:\/\/)(?!www\.)
```

Replace with:

```
$1www.
```

```js
const regex = /(https?:\/\/)(?!www\.)/g;
const str = `the url is http://google.com http://www.google.com https://google.com https://google.com`;
const subst = `$1www.`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(https?:\/\/(?!www))
```

replace the matches with:

```
$1www.
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JhMN6t/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `https?:\/\/` - matches either `http://` or `https://`
- `(?!www)` - matches only if the current position is not followed by `www`
- `()` - parenthesis to capture the whole match in a group

Replace the whole match with Group 1 followed by `www.`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

`/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)/gm`